# HTML wrong formatting

Tags: html, css, forms, formatting, html-input

I am trying to create a simple login page, but I keep stumbling upon a problem. An input I put in a form (which is in turn in a table) goes to the top left corner of the page. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="size: 16px; font-family: Comic Sans MS">LOGIN</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form>
                        <input type="email" name="mail"><br>
                        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                        <input type="reset"></td>
                    </form>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I also have a couple lines of css "code"

```
table.center {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I don't quite get why the poor "submit" input won't stay in place.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi. What does stay in place mean here. Could you give all of the css and a working example, and a better explanation to how it is suppose to look.

Comment: it looks like it's `</td>`after `<input type="reset">` that should be `<br>` or you could also remove it.

Comment: I would like the button to be underneath the inputs, as they're all centered but, for some reason, it jumps all the way to the top left corner.

Comment: @pierre THANK YOU I had overlooked it. Sorry for wasting your time on something this little. I'm very grateful though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nesting of the td around the form is wrong. the /td needs to come after the submit so that all of the form plus the submit are in the cell.

Here's the changed code:

```html
<style>
table.center {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="size: 16px; font-family: Comic Sans MS">LOGIN</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form>
                        <input type="email" name="mail"><br>
                        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                        <input type="reset">
                    </form>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
                    </td>
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was so obsessed with it I just couldn't see it. Thank you really

Comment: @EmanuelePolonia the answer is kinda correct but not all the way. You are closing the </td>, but there is a opening <td> with no content or closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the submit element inside form?
Otherwise you can just make a button. I might be wrong here tho but worth a try.

```
<form>
    <input type="email" name="mail"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="reset"></td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sure you can, add an id to the form, `<button type="submit" form="my-form">Submit</button>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Turns out I was stressing so much about this situation that I have overlooked a simple </td> which was out of place.